# Does using ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()) in the IOStreams library handle arbitrarily massive streams?

Tags: c++, iostream, standards

In the C++ standard (section 27.6.1.3\24), for the
istream `ignore()` function in the IOStreams library, it implies that if you supply an argument for 'n' of `numeric_limits::max()`, it will continue to ignore characters
forever up until the delimiter is found, even way beyond the actual
max value for streamsize (i.e. the 'n' argument is interpreted as infinite).

For the gcc implementation this does indeed appear to be how
`ignore()` is implemented, but I'm still unclear as to
whether this is implementation specific, or mandated by the standard.
Can someone who knows this well confirm that this is guaranteed by a
standard compliant iostreams library?

Comment: you mean `std::numeric_limits`, surely?

Comment: What do you do to provide numeric_limits::max() numbers of characters to istream object?

Comment: which istream object are your using and how do you test that condition? It cannot be cin cos it roughly takes more than 20 hours to type in characters that much. I'm more interested in your testing way instead of actual answer:)

Comment: @Eric: Well, if you compile on a 32-bit machine (without LFS enabled), then doing this on a file larger than 4GB should reach the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard says that `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is a special value that doesn't affect the number of characters skipped.

> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1). After constructing a sentry object, extracts characters and discards them. Characters are extracted until any of the following occurs:
>    -- if `n != numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` (18.3.2), n characters are extracted
>    -- end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls setstate(eofbit), which may throw ios_base::failure (27.5.5.4));
>    -- traits::eq_int_type(traits::to_int_type(c), delim) for the next available input character c (in which case c is extracted).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about - it specifies what happens if n != numeric_limits::max(), but does not specify what happens if n **does** equal numeric_limits::max(); hence the question.

Comment: My interpretation of that is that if n == numeric_limits::max(), the characters are not counted against the limit. We are just looking for the delimiter or end-of-file. On the other hand, streamsize will be one of the largest integers we have, so it would be hard to reach that value anyway.

Comment: I believe this should be read as follows: (1) there are three conditions that can terminate the loop. (2) One of them is that n!=max and n characters have been extracted. (3) One of them is EOF. (4) One of them is that the delimiter is matched. If n == max then (2) can never happen, so there are only 2 possible termination conditions. In all cases where the standard says "if X, Y", that means Y only applies when X is true. If X is false, Y is irrelevant.

Comment: An alternative, pedantically logical reading is that when n == max, the first condition "if X then Y" is vacuously true since X is false, and hence extraction stops immediately. This is *not* what the standard means when it phrases things this way. Anyway, there is no reasonable reading of that paragraph which tells you that "n characters have been extracted" is a termination condition when n == max. We must therefore conclude that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore):

```
istream&  istream::ignore ( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );
```

Extract and discard characters
Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them.

The extraction ends when n characters have been extracted and discarded **or** when the character delim is found, **whichever comes first**. In the latter case, the delim character itself is also extracted.

In your case, when numeric_limits::max() number of characters have been reached, the first condition is met.

[Per Bo]

However, according to spec, the above case is applied only when n is **not** equal to `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`.

Comment: No, the standard explicitly says that this is only the case when n != numeric_limits()::max. (Have a look at the extract in Bo's answer.)

Comment: Never take cplusplus's word for anything. It over-simplifies, because it thinks it's better to have some description of what a function does than to fail to understand an *accurate* description of what a function does.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for your advice. Referring to the spec is the final way we can do to resolve such things.