# Reading the second integer from a file which uses getline()

Tags: c++, getline

I have a text file which can be seen below. I wish to read the file and then use the second integer in the file. However, the code which I am currently using simply takes the first integer and the string. Whilst I want it to take the second integer and the string.

So my question is, how is this possible? And can it be done with `getLine()`?

The file which I am trying to read and the code can be seen below:

File:

```
10202 CE151 17.5
10105 CE151 99.9
10202 CE151 5.6
10406 CE301 59.8
10103 CE151 75.5
10709 CE204 67.2
```

Code:

```
string mod;
float mark;

getline(file2, s2);
istringstream line(s2);
line >> mark;
line >> mod;

cout << mod << endl;
cout << mark << endl;
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're talking about integers, but `mark` is a `float`, and the second number on each line is not an integer... Did you perhaps mean you want to read the second *number* (as opposed to *integer*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line >> reg;
line >> mod;
line >> mark;

cout << reg << endl;
cout << mod << endl;
cout << mark << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Second integer is on the second line, so you need to [skip a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878052/does-using-ignorenumeric-limitsstreamsizemax-in-the-iostreams-library-ha)

```
(#include <limits> header for this)
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

Then you need to read the integer into a variable

```
int number= 0;
file>> number;
```

Now you have the second integer in `number`.